Thom Space over Grassmannian as a Homotopy Orbit
Let $U, V, W$ be inner product spaces where $U$ carries a natural $O(n)$-action. I'd like to verify Arone's claim (Arone's Stable Stiefel Manifold Splitting paper, p. 1208)
$$ \operatorname{Gr}_n(V)^{U \oplus \operatorname{hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, W)} \simeq (S^U \wedge V_n(V)_+ \wedge S^{nW})_{hO(n)} $$ where $V_n(V)$ denotes the Stiefel manifold of $n$-frames inside $V$ and where on the left side I'm denoting the Thom space.
I expected this to be a quick consequence of the fact $(S^{\rho})_{hG} \simeq \operatorname{Th}(\rho \times_G EG \to BG)$ for a $G$-representation $\rho$, but I couldn't get this to work, as the space inside the brackets on the right is not a sphere and $BO(n)$ is not $\operatorname{Gr}_n(V)$. I believe that one should somehow combine $V_n(V)$ and $hO(n)$ to produce $\operatorname{Gr}_n(V)$, but I don't see how. Does anyone have an idea for this equivalence?

The Thom space is homeomorphic to the strict orbit space $(S^U \wedge V_n(V)+ \wedge S^{nW}){O(n)}$, and because the action of $O(n)$ on the space in the parentheses is free, the homotopy orbit space is equivalent to the strict orbit space.

@GregoryArone Awesome to see you here, Greg. That was very helpful, I spelled out some details below. I hope you had a good time in Bonn at the Unstable workshop, we met very briefly (I'm a student from Markus), I enjoyed your talk!

Greg's comment made me realize that I didn't really understand what $\operatorname{Gr}_n(V)^{U \oplus \operatorname{hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, W)}$ meant. This uses that there is a principle $O(n)$-bundle $O(n) \to V_n(V) \to \operatorname{Gr_n}(V)$, so the Thom space is really the Thom space of the associated vector bundle, so we may compute:
$$ \begin{align*} \operatorname{Gr}_n(V)^{U \oplus \operatorname{hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, W)} &= \operatorname{Th} \left((U \oplus nW) \times_{O(n)} V_n(V) \to \operatorname{Gr}_n(V) \right) 
\\ &\cong (S^U \wedge S^{nW}) \wedge_{O(n)} V_n(V)
\\ &= (S^U \wedge S^{nW} \wedge V_n(V))_{O(n)}
\\ &\simeq (S^U \wedge S^{nW} \wedge V_n(V))_{hO(n)} \end{align*}. $$ The second line is by taking the definition of Thom spaces that takes spheres bundles and then collapses the section at $\infty$ and the smash product $\wedge$ is responsible for the collapsing. The last step is because $O(n)$ acts freely as Greg explained.
